# Is it possible to Inject the NestJS app created in main.ts into a module service?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

Assuming you have the basic NestJS setup:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.enableCors(corsOptions);

  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      validateCustomDecorators: true,
      transform: true,
      whitelist: true,
      exceptionFactory: exceptionFactory,
    }),
  );
  app.useGlobalFilters(new CustomExceptionsFilter());

  const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT);
  await app.listen(port);
}
```

Can I access the `app` variable created with NestFactory from a service in a different module?

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  constructor(
    ...
  ) {}

  async useApp(): Promise<any> {
    const app = ... // use Injected app instance created from AppModule
  }
```

I've tried importing AppModule and creating a NestFactory again, but it just resolves into redundancies.

Answer (score 1):

`NestFactory.create` will create the `app`, which depends on modules & their providers. Using `app` before it has been created does not make sense.

---

Instead, you could tell us what you're trying to do with that `app` at `TestService`.

Comment: I'm trying to access and list all schemas and DTOs declared within the project without using Swagger.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the `app` instance itself from the Nest containers, you could simply export the app once it is created by `NestFactory.create()`.

However, if you're looking for the instance of `AppModule`, this bellow snippet might help you.

```js
const app = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule);
```